# String value for c:set throws NumberFormatException

Tags: jsf, jstl

I want to generate the URL for an image in JSF with the following code...

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{cc.attrs.index == 0}">
        <c:set var="image" value="image.png" />
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="image" value="image1.png" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<img src="#{image}" />
```

But when I run this, I get a NumberFormatException:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "image.png"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELArithmetic$DoubleDelegate.coerce(ELArithmetic.java:148)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELArithmetic.coerce(ELArithmetic.java:373)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELArithmetic.add(ELArithmetic.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstPlus.getValue(AstPlus.java:57)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:208)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:140)
    ...
```

So now my question: Is it true, that `c:set` does not accept String values?

---

BTW, when I use a parameter, for example

```
        <c:set var="image" value="#{cc.attrs.index}" />
```

everything's fine, but well, the URL is not the correct one.

---

My maven dependencies:

- org.apache.myfaces.core.myfaces-api 2.1.7
- org.apache.myfaces.core.myfaces-impl 2.1.7
- javax.el.el-api 2.2

Comment: What happens if you put the string value in between the opening and closing tags: `<c:set var="image">image.png</c:set>`?

Comment: Then I get a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pure JSF to solve this problem

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{(cc.attrs.index eq 0)? 'image.png' : 'image1.png' }" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is, that there will be some more conditions and I wanted to build the final link step by step. So, I start with `image`, add `1` if neccessary, add `_1` if the next condition applies and so on. Finally I add `.png` and the URL can be used with the image tag.

Comment: So you're using the logic to build the image name? Why not building it in the ManagedBean and then just retrieves the name of the image?

Comment: Because I think images names are part of the view in MVC and should not be part of the managed bean. I already thought about implementing my own EL-tag so that I can call `#{myTag:imageUrl(param1, param2)}` (not sure if this is possible).